# Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND postman when i try to do a request

Tags: postman

I have this error when i do a request to a url, but it only happen in my pc, i have proved it in 4 pcs, with the same url and the same parameters, and in the mine is the only one that shows this error

[image]